# NameError: global name 'Path' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm a beginner of learning GUI. My python version is 2.7,and I'm using windows

what should I do to be able to change the value of "path" by clicking button?

here is the part of my code.  :)

```
class Sign_page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        img_path = "C:/"
        Path = tk.Text(self, width = 45, height=1)
        Path.insert("end",img_path)
        Path.grid(row=2,column=0)

        ask_path = tk.Button(self, text = "...", command = lambda: asking_path(self))
        ask_path.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

and this part is out of class "Sign_page"

```
def asking_path(self):
    fileName = askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/")
    img_path = fileName
    Path.delete("1.0","end")
    Path.insert("end",img_path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path` is not accessible from `asking_path` because it's not defined in the scope. One solution is to set an attribute on the instance when you create `Path` in `__init__`. In general, you should use lowercased variable names for Python variables ("`path`"), and title case for class names ("`SignPage`").

```
class SignPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        path = tk.Text(self, width = 45, height=1)
        path.insert("end",img_path)
        path.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.path = path
        ...

    def asking_path(self):
        ...
        self.path.delete("1.0","end")
        self.path.insert("end",img_path)
```

Comment: Thx for answering, and yes that works. also thx for the reminding. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about this error..!! django is using 'path' instead of 'url' in its latest version.
you just have to import path in url.py file
use this:-

from django.urls import path